# How to check whether SOAP fault is being handled gracefully?

Tags: soap, junit, mockito, soapfault

I'm using JUnit and Mockito in order to test whether my SOAP web service handles SOAP faults gracefully and doesn't throw any unwanted exceptions for example.

So up until now, as you can see from the code below, I'm only testing whether a `SOAPFaultException` is being thrown (of course it does, I threw it). I wonder how I could check though whether any other exception would be thrown when receiving the SOAP fault.

Also is there any way to mock a SOAP fault without throwing an exception (`SOAPFaultException`)?

```
public class SOAPFaultsTest {

private MyObj myObj = (MyObj) mock(IMockClass.class);

@Before
public void create() {

    SOAPFault soapFault = null;
    try {
        soapFault = SOAPFactory.newInstance(SOAPConstants.SOAP_1_1_PROTOCOL).createFault();
        soapFault.setFaultString("unable to create new native thread");
        soapFault.setFaultCode(QName.valueOf("soap:Server"));
    } catch (SOAPException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Define behaviour of myObj mock object
    when(myObj.randomMethod(any(RandomClass.class))).thenThrow(new SOAPFaultException(soapFault));
}

// Here I'm testing whether invoking myObj's randomMethod with a RandomClass object as an argument throws a SOAPFaultException. 
// It does because this is how I defined its behaviour. 
// What I really want to test is whether receiving a SOAP fault at any time is going to cause any trouble.
@Test(expected=SOAPFaultException.class)
public void testSOAPException() throws SOAPFaultException {
    RandomClass rc = new RandomClass();
    myObj.randomMethod(rc);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you go with a full-stack mock (i.e. spawn an Endpoint on a local socket, point the client there). Then create a soap fault and let the mock throw an [appropriate exception](https://github.com/skjolber/mockito-soap-cxf/blob/master/src/main/java/com/skjolberg/mockito/soap/SoapServiceFault.java) over the wire. If you're using CXF, I've created a [simple JUnit Rule](https://github.com/skjolber/mockito-soap-cxf) which does this, see the test method [SoapServiceRuleTest.processSoapCallWithException()](https://github.com/skjolber/mockito-soap-cxf/blob/master/src/test/java/com/skjolberg/mockito/soap/SoapServiceRuleTest.java#L98).

As a general strategy, I suggest you make an abstract 'happy case' unit test which you then sabotage one call at a time by doing reset on the mock with each test method and adding thenThrow(..) correspondingly.

Comment: I wish there was some webservice URL (like testSoapFault.com) which I can use to test SoapFaultClientException :)